# Syntax error (comma) in query expression?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

Sooo I'm currently coding this second year project that I have about some library system. Just wanted to ask reallll quick if anyone could respond to this question reall fast. In a part of my coding, under my **btnUpdate_Click** where obviously is functioned to update the information the books in the Books table. I got an error msg when executing the program where it says **Syntax error (comma) in query expression**. Here's my code :

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class BookDetails
Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\msi\\Desktop\\UITM\\DIPLOMA CS110\\SEM 3\\CSC301\\groupproject\\ReadObrite\\ReadObrite\\User.accdb")
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

    Public Sub view()
        conn.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Books ", conn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub BookDetails_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'UserDataSet.Books' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.BooksTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UserDataSet.Books)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Books ", conn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        conn.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "Update Books set ISBN = '" + TextBox12.Text + "' where Ttile = '" + TextBox11.Text + "', Author = '" + TextBox10.Text + "', Production = '" + TextBox9.Text + "', Category = '" + TextBox8.Text + "' and Year = '" + TextBox7.Text + "'"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
        btnSearch_Click(New Object, New EventArgs())
        view()
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Me.BooksBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        conn.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Books values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("New book is added")
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()
        TextBox5.Clear()
        TextBox6.Clear()
        conn.Close()
        conn.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Books ", conn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()
        TextBox5.Clear()
        TextBox6.Clear()
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        TextBox12.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBox11.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBox10.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBox9.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
        TextBox8.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value.ToString()
        TextBox7.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value.ToString()
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub refresh()
        If txtSearch.Text = "" Then
            view()
        End If
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        conn.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Books Where ISBN = '" + txtSearch.Text + "' or Title = '" + txtSearch.Text + "' "
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        conn.Close()
        refresh()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I tried changing all the commas to 'And'. but then a new error occured.

Comment: Don't concat strings into sql, use db parameters. Does the command text run on the db when you run it directly?

Comment: Is "Ttile" the correct name of the title column?

Comment: You should not be posting all that code. Post ONLY the code that is specifically relevant to the issue. You've shown six different queries there, when you should only be showing the one that is causing the specific issue you're asking about. Not only that, you're asking us about a SQL issue without even showing us the SQL code. The VB code that builds the SQL code is not the SQL code. If you follow Andrew Mortimer's advice then this issue will almost certainly go away but that doesn't change the fact that you've included irrelevant information and excluded relevant information.

Comment: `but then a new error occured.` - and what was the new error? I'd have expected "and" to be correct rather than `,` but I don't do a lot with Access SQL any more.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update Books set ISBN = '" + TextBox12.Text + "' WHERE Ttile = '" + TextBox11.Text + "' AND Author = '" + TextBox10.Text + "' AND Production = '" + TextBox9.Text + "' AND Category = '" + TextBox8.Text + "' AND [Year] = '" + TextBox7.Text + "'"
```

notes :

- Year is a SQL protected name so enclose with []
- comma not supported in all SQL declination
- as mentionned by IFrank, maybe error in "Ttile" column name - may throw an invalid column name error message
- be carreful with controls text contents : clean them with TextBoxXX.Text.replace("'","'") or use parametized query

Comment: SQL concatenation should be strongly discouraged. Use parameters.